# Jenkins pipeline and Docker multi-stage builds howto

Tags: docker, jenkins

### Question

I have to configure CI/CD for number of Git repositories with help of Jenkins (and DockerHub as CD target). I did that with help of Docker multi-stage build (see Considerations). I'm afraid to misunderstand/overcomplicate a simple idea.

*Is Jenkins + Docker multi-stage build = best/good practice? Am I applying the idea in the correct way?*

### Considerations

From [this presentation](https://www.slideshare.net/Docker/build-publish-deploy-and-test-docker-images-and-containers-with-jenkins-workflow) I assume using Docker inside Jenkins is a good idea. After reading an article [Using Multi-Stage Builds to Simplify and Standardize Build Processes](https://medium.com/capital-one-tech/multi-stage-builds-and-dockerfile-b5866d9e2f84), Docker multi-stage builds looks to be the next step of using Jenkins + Docker.

Answers to [similar question](https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/cw6gz4/dockerfile_or_jenkinsfile_for_multi_stage_build/) also say Docker multi-stage makes sense, but doesn't provide an example of realisation.

### Implementation

Jenkins creates pipeline from SCM repository.

*Git repository*

```
Dockerfile
Jenkinsfile
project-folder
  |-src
  |-pom.xml
```

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM alpine as source
RUN apk --update --no-cache add git
COPY project-folder repo

FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-8 as test
COPY --from=source repo repo
WORKDIR repo
RUN mvn clean test

FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-8 as build
COPY --from=test repo repo
WORKDIR repo
RUN mvn clean package

FROM openjdk:8 as final
MAINTEINER xxx <xxx@gmail.com>
LABEL owner="xxx"
COPY --from=build repo/target/some-lib-1.8.jar /usr/local/some-lib.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/usr/local/some-lib.jar"]
```

*Jenkinsfile*

I used `docker build --target` for more granularity on Jenkins UI.

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

def imageId = "use-name/image-name:1.$BUILD_NUMBER"

pipeline {

    agent {
        label 'docker'  # separate agent (launched as JAR on host machine) to avoid running docker inside docker
    }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh "docker build --no-cache --target test -t ${imageId} ."
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh "docker build --target build -t ${imageId} ."
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Image') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh "docker build --target final -t ${imageId} ."
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                script {
                    docker.withRegistry('' , 'dockerhub') {
                        dockerImage = docker.build("${imageId}")
                        dockerImage.push()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Clean') {
          steps{
            sh "docker rmi ${imageId}"
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, multi-stage build is a best practice at the moment. Your implementation is fine, but personally I do not see much sense in splitting steps in Jenkinsfile, especially if you are dealing with multiple projects. Just do a full docker build, and if there is a failure - you would know where it happened from logs.

Comment: I plan to create a similar setup. Do you fetch test and coverage data from the docker image builds, and if yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

following taleodor's answer I would suggest next jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    label 'docker'  # separate agent (launched as JAR on host machine) to avoid running docker inside docker
  }
  environment {
    imageId = 'use-name/image-name:1.$BUILD_NUMBER'
    docker_registry = 'your_docker_registry'
    docker_creds = credentials('your_docker_registry_creds')
  }
  stages {
    stage('Docker build') {
      steps {
        sh "docker build --no-cache --force-rm -t ${imageId} ."
      }
    }
    stage('Docker push') {
      steps {
        sh'''
          docker login $docker_registry --username $docker_creds_USR --password $docker_creds_PSW
          docker push $imageId
          docker logout
        '''
      }
    }
    stage('Clean') {
      steps{
        sh "docker rmi ${imageId}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you! Just one question before accepting the answer - why do you prefer explicit Docker credentials management? In my pipeline I just implicitly use the creds configured through Jenkins UI.

Comment: sorry, can't resist to ask one more side-question - will this pipeline work in case of multiple parallel builds? Means SCM plugin pull the code into the same folder, and I though about pulling the code inside Dockerfile (but finally considered that idea as bad)

Comment: suppose it will work in parallel stages. also I prefer to use declarative style of pipelines. additionally use --force-rm option to remove not only final image but also intermediate containers: sh "docker build --no-cache --force-rm -t ${imageId} ."

Comment: @DmitriTarasevich thanks! I'll do that. Could you please clarify regarding the explicit vs implicit DockerHub credentials?

Comment: As I said - I prefer to use declarative style of pipelines. I provide credentials in declarative style in my example. Use any style you like. In declarative way - install mask passwords plugin to hide credentials in output.